# I don't have my 12 word question but I do have my PIN and my computers MAC address

Tags: hive

I have been using my Hivewallet on my laptop for over 3 months and not once has it asked me for my 12 security words. In the past I figured it had picked up my MAC address because all it ever asked for was my PIN. I recently had problem and all my newer folders have been destroyed and cannot be taken.

I was hoping there would be a way I could still get into my folder. It has about $500-$550 worth of bitcoins and I did nothing wrong. I know everything that went on - even $750 worth or BTC that was taken only hours before the $500 of BTC was sent.

Comment: `Please work with me. You have been very good and I would like to continue to do business with you. I you don't hand over my money, although small we will not do business with you again.` Who are you talking to?

Comment: @NickODell I've edited that out of the question.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure Hive is like the other web wallets in that they literally can't access your funds, they are encrypted. You would have been told in no uncertain terms to keep those 12 words safe and secure, it is not their fault if you haven't done that. Passwords are not recoverable on other web wallets either (e.g. blockchain.info).

Good luck, there's a chance some polite emails to their support may yield something if you have enough info for them to investigate but don't be surprised if they can't help.

Next time, store your funds somewhere safer and just keep day-to-day funds on the web wallet.

Answer (score 2):

The PIN-based security is not based on your MAC address (which could be easily spoofed), [it's based on a locally-stored private key](https://github.com/hivewallet/hive-js/wiki/Hive-Web-FAQ) that's encrypted with a token stored on their server, which they only give to you when presented with the right PIN (and which they erase if presented with 5 incorrect PINs).

If the file was only deleted and not physically overwritten yet, there may be a chance that you can still recover this deleted data from your hard drive. Without this file, Hive is completely unable to give you access to your wallet. If you want to try to recover this, stop using the computer immediately, and begin attempting to recover the data.

**There's nothing Hive can do for you** without this file or, better, the 12 word passphrase. You should have recorded the 12 word passphrase, as was suggested.